# How long should someone wait for before accepting an answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I have faced this dilemma a couple of times. Often I get responses for posts within the first hour. On some occasions one of those responses helps me resolve the issue.

One way to go would be to accept such an answer immediately (which is also fair to the person who has responded to the post) . On the other hand its hard to get more responses for posts with an accepted answer.

The other way to go would be to wait for a day or two so that enough people get an opportunity to respond. In the process one may end up getting a better response. (It also benefits other members who may run into the same issue. )This has been my observation for posts related to less popular tags , which probably gets single digit views in the first hour.

I was wondering what other members in this forum think about waiting long enough before accepting an answer. Is it a fair thing to do?

[image]

I have also noticed Stackoverflow putting a banner over questions with no accpeted answer. So I am guessing the forum internally has a way to "guessing" and prompting members to accept answers. How does it do that ?

Comment: Accept an answer when you feel your question has been answered. If the first answer solves your problem in a meaningful and useful way, feel free to accept. _Nothing stops you from accepting a different answer down the road, should a better one come in._ In other words, it's entirely up to you how long you should wait. If you get five answers in two days, and none of them answer your question satisfactorily, then don't accept them. If it's important, bounty it. If not, keep researching and you can add/accept your own answer if you find one. :)

Comment: Take your time to accept. If an answer fully answers the question, with detail and special cases, you might want to accept it faster, but otherwise give the activity time to simmer down. Also, before you accept, be sure it really answers your question (and please, only *that* question, not all follow-up and otherwise related ones). Anyway, there's no need to be hasty, or letting anyone pressure you into deciding fast.

Comment: @Kendra I guess thats one way to go. But Its always hard to get responses for posts with an accepted answer. Bcoz, the incentive to respond is gone :) . Which is why i posted the Q.

Comment: Which is why you should only accept an answer when you feel your question has been answered. Like I said, if you get five answers that don't completely satisfy you, you don't have to accept them. You can keep waiting. And, also like I said, you can always change the accepted answer, so if someone thinks they can post a better answer, there is still the possibility that the OP will change the accepted answer, and if not, they may well get more upvotes than the accepted answer. (Upvotes end up paying out more for good answers, anyway, most of the time.)

Comment: Why do you still need responses to your answer after your quesiton has already been resolved?

Comment: @SamIam In lot of cases there is always a more efficient , cleaner solution  to fix the same issue. It will come along if one gives the post enough exposure and time.

Comment: @Sam, because further responses can be better than the accepted one, of course. But the questioner will be notified if a new answer is posted, and can take the appropriate action, including unaccepting the previously-best answer and accepting the new one. (Don't do that too much in sequence though -- repeated +/-15 deltas in reputation have a tendency to piss people off.)